# Getting value of one string variable correctly in Java if i do the debug but same values is null when i run the program

Tags: java

I am facing pretty weird problem here. I have one java project in eclipse. When I do the debug on program, It returns me value of one String variable properly, But when I run same program, i get that value as a null.
What could be the problem ?

```
/*Piece of code*/
version = FindVersion(fileName,filePath,tmpDir);
/*Find version function*/
String version = null;
        String finalvalue = null;
        File script = File.createTempFile("xxxxx", ".vbs");  
        File result = File.createTempFile("xxxxx", ".txt"); 
        String fullPath = tmpDir + filePath + fileName;        
        FileWriter fwrt = new FileWriter(script); 
        fwrt.write("Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n");
        fwrt.write("Wscript.Echo objFSO.GetFileVersion(\"" + fullPath + "\")"); 
        fwrt.close(); 



    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c"  
            + "cscript "  
            + script.getAbsolutePath()  
            + " >" + result.getAbsolutePath());  
    int ret = p.waitFor();  

    if (ret != 0) 
    {  
        System.out.println("Error :(  Exit code = " + ret);  
    } 
    else
    {  
        BufferedReader rd = null;  
        rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(result));            
        while((version = rd.readLine()) != null )
        {
            if(version.matches("^[\\d\\.]+$"))
            {
                finalvalue = version;
                rd.close();
                script.delete();  
                result.delete();                    
                return finalvalue;
                //break;
            }   
        }
        rd.close();
        script.delete();  
        result.delete();            
    }
    return null;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried checking the contents of the temp file after the script is run? If so, is the value that matches your regex in the text contained within it? As a debug measure, I would have it print out the entire contents of the file so I could see what was actually in the file when it malfunctioned.

Comment: What value? and where do you put your break point?

Comment: version and in turn finalValue is getting null value. I put break point at function call and as well as  this line : if(version.matches("^[\\d\\.]+$")). Content of output file seems OK for me. I am getting perfect output when i debug this program but gets null values when i run same program

Comment: If version is null first time through then I will restate what I already said but even stronger this time: Check the entire contents of the temp file after the process is done. It's probably completely empty.

Comment: Content of temp file is like this one: 
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

12.0.0.49974

So when I run this program at third iteration it gets null value and i think it terminates from their.
But again same thing, When I debug this program exactly same temp file is getting generated and this time While loop goes to 4th line and find out the actual version and returns it properly.

Comment: http://shortText.com/0sx7q4p7i1i

File looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that *`version`* never matches that pattern

```
if(version.matches("^[\\d\\.]+$"))
```

So, after reading the whole file, it gets null again, and *`finalvalue`* never takes a value.
Thus you get the two of them as nulls.

Does the flow get into that `if` condition ?
Are you sure that this pattern matches what you want ? `"^[\\d\\.]+$"`

---

Also is this correct ? Should there be a space or something ? or is it just a weird string split you have there ?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c"
                                      +"cscript "  ..
```

translates to:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /ccscript "  ..
```

Comment: Program runs perfectly fine when i  do debug, but it does not run when i run and not debug

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting the flow of your program. If version were to be null as you stated in one of your comments, the while loop would be finished, so you would never be returning finalValue in the first place; instead, the last line `return null;` would be executing. Put a debug line inside the while loop to verify.

```
while(...)
    System.out.println(version);
```

How are you verifying that "version is null and in tern finalValue is null"?

(edit)
Also note that this is assuming you mean that version is null immediately (first iteration of while loop) when you state that "version is null."

Comment: `version` takes a value through `rd.readLine()`. `return finalValue` is executed only if `version` isn't null, which means that the file wasn't empty, and if it matches that pattern.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not understanding your point. Are you just restating what I said in a different way? That was my point. `return finalValue` is not reached if the file is empty. He said that `version` is null, which means that `return finalValue` will **not** get executed.